# Stop repetition of CSS Code

Tags: css

I have this 3x chunk of CSS serving 3 of my HTML Divs, the actual problem is that the code is repeated three times with only one change, that ofcourse is the background color of the divs: `background-color: #xxxxx;`  my question, is how would I go about not repeating this 3x block, but only keep 1 block but the color change on each of my Divs is different for each of these offers.

Is this even possible, or am I going about it the right way at the moment?

```
.BlueOffer {
width: 300px;
height: 25px;
background-color: #0099ff;
opacity: 0.4;
font-size: 22px;
border-bottom: 1px SOLID #555555;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
border-top-right-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
.OrangeOffer {
width: 300px;
height: 25px;
background-color: #F90;
opacity: 0.4;
font-size: 22px;
border-bottom: 1px SOLID #555555;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
border-top-right-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}

.GreenOffer {
width: 300px;
height: 25px;
background-color: #66FF00;
opacity: 0.4;
font-size: 22px;
border-bottom: 1px SOLID #555555;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
border-top-right-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
```

The only change is: `background-color: #0099ff;`

HTML Code follows:

```
<div class='GreenOffer'>GREEN OFFER</div>
<div class='OrangeOffer'>ORANGE OFFER</div>
<div class='BlueOffer'>BLUE OFFER</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

There's no need for multiple classes.  Just define the common properties up front, then specify the unique ones individually:

```
.BlueOffer, .OrangeOffer, .GreenOffer {
    width: 300px;
    height: 25px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px SOLID #555555;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}

.BlueOffer {
    background-color: #0099ff;
}
.OrangeOffer {
    background-color: #F90;
}

.GreenOffer {
    background-color: #66FF00;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use more then one class on an element.

```
<div class='Offer GreenOffer'>GREEN OFFER</div>
<div class='Offer OrangeOffer'>ORANGE OFFER</div>
<div class='Offer BlueOffer'>BLUE OFFER</div>

.Offer {
    width: 300px;
    height: 25px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px SOLID #555555;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}

.BlueOffer {
    background-color: #0099ff;
}
.OrangeOffer {
    background-color: #F90;
}

.GreenOffer {
    background-color: #66FF00;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, which are great, you could use an "ends with" selector:

```
[class$=Offer] {
    width: 300px;
    height: 25px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px SOLID #555555;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}

.BlueOffer {
    background-color: #0099ff;
}
.OrangeOffer {
    background-color: #F90;
}

.GreenOffer {
    background-color: #66FF00;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer a more hierarchical CSS selector approach, one that also tries to avoid undesired changes:

```
.offer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 25px;
  /* ... etc ... */
}

.offer.blue{
  background-color: #0099ff;
}
.offer.green{
  background-color: #66ff00;
}
```

You apply it the same way:

```
<div class="offer">Standard Offer</div>
<div class="offer green">Green Offer</div>
```

However, the difference is, the css selector `.offer.green` selects elements that have *both* the `offer` and the `green` class.

Having just...

```
.green{ /*...*/ }
```

could cause problems if you some OTHER element on your page you also want to have a green color but it's slightly different in some way.  Perhaps green text and not a green background. Ouch, imagine if you had that bug?  Green text on a green background? =)

You could use...

```
.offerGreen{ /*...*/ }
```

Your introducing more writing than necessary.  While relatively insignificant, it will also increase the size of your page because...

```
<div class="offer offerGreen"></div>
```

is more characters than...

```
<div class="offer green"></div>
```

although it is just text and with gzip compression, the practical impact is not worth optimizing for unless you're uber optimizing.

I hope that helps!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple classes

```
.offer{
    width: 300px;
    height: 25px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #555555;

    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
        -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
            border-top-right-radius: 15px;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
        -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
            border-top-left-radius: 15px;

     /*or you could use
     border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
     */
}

.Blue{background-color: #0099ff;}
.Orange{background-color: #F90;}
.Green{background-color: #66FF00;}
```

And apply it them

```
<div class='Green offer'>GREEN OFFER</div>
<div class='Orange offer'>ORANGE OFFER</div>
<div class='Blue offer'>BLUE OFFER</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using more than one `class`.

**CSS:**

```
.offer{    
width: 300px;
height: 25px;
opacity: 0.4;
font-size: 22px;
border-bottom: 1px SOLID #555555;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
border-top-right-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
.green {
background-color: #66FF00;
}
```

**HTML**

`<div class='offer green'>Green OFFER</div>`

Answer (score 0):

you can either have multiple classes per object or have a block apply to more than one class:

```
.OrangeOffer, .BlueOffer, .GreenOffer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 25px;
  opacity: 0.4;
  font-size: 22px;
  border-bottom: 1px SOLID #555555;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
.OrangeOffer {
  background-color: #F90;
}
.GreenOffer {
  background-color: #66FF00;
}
.BlueOffer {
  background-color: #0099ff;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To prevent repeating CSS code is possible to use CSS framework like `LESS` or `SASS` for example. You can use with them **variables, nesting, functions,** they have nicely made **inheritance** and you can use **mixins** too.

- http://lesscss.org/
- http://sass-lang.com/

There are many other CSS frameworks too, so its your choice. But I recommend CSS FW.